# Jersey on JBoss 6.1 - Deployment fails for a very simple application if I provide web.xml

Tags: jboss, jersey, jax-rs, jboss6.x

I prepared a simple application using **Jersey** (latest version) and tried to deploy it on **JBoss 6.1 Final** server without the web.xml file (using **@ApplicationPath** over my Application class) and it worked fine. (though I had to remove **resteasy.deployer** from server/default/deployers). But **when I added the following web.xml** (and removed @ApplicationPath),

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>org.daud.InformationApplication</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>org.daud.InformationApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/information/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

it gave me "**Error calling onStartup for servlet container initializer**". The full error was :

```
06:42:01,649 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/jersey
06:42:01,649 ERROR [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.JBossContextConfig] Error calling onStartup for servlet container initializer: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.addServletWithExistingRegistration(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:239) [:1.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:129) [:1.11]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.JBossContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(JBossContextConfig.java:189) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3823) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:294) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.1.0.Final
```

My **Application** file (InformationApplication.java) is :

```
public class InformationApplication extends PackagesResourceConfig {
    public InformationApplication() {
        super("org.daud.resources");
    }
}
```